# Spotify loudness normalization

Tags: spotify

Spotify has a loudness normalization option (called something like "play all songs at the same volume").

Please - does anyone know what algorithm is used to calculate the loudness of a track?  Is it at all related to the broadcast loudness algorithm ITU-R BS.1770?

And how does Spotify then handle clips if it ends up scaling the clip up to loudness normalize it?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but I'm not sure my question comes under "software development methods and practices, requirements, architecture, and design, quality assurance and testing, configuration, build, and release management"

Comment: If you have an issue with code, you ask on StackOverflow. Otherwise, PSE.

Comment: Ok, thanks Ivan.  I'll try.

Comment: @IvanRubinson this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat as-is, it is a poor fit. If he edits a bit, it can be a valid design question.